# save Canvas drawing in html5 phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I have draw drawing on canvas and want to save it as image(jpg/png) on phone internal memory.
How can I do this.
Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two choices to do this.
1) Use Phonegap filewriter api [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.1.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileWriter)

2) you can write a custom phonegap plugin, basically send the image data to ios/android and have objective C / java write the image to the filesystem.

Each of these has benefits. I prefer the phonegap plugin, but I have more experience with plugins. The phonegap api would be quicker though, if your needs are basic. Good Luck!

Comment: does the filewriter support JPG?